# What kind of widget is this and how can I set it up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have seen this l kind of behaviour (I call it widget) in some apps that handle images. Stackoverflow android app does it too.

When you click on an image, an AlertDialog like widget with zoom-in and zoom-out buttons comes up. You can also double click to see the original size of the image.

For example :

[image: If you're on stackoverflow android app, click this image to see the effect.]

Please, what l kind of widget is this and how do I set it up.

Comment: This can be custom dialog , which has "set cancellable = true" (if you click outside it , it closes), plus it also has a zoom controller on its layout. In order to make it, make a custom layout with the things mentioned above, pass them to the setView method on the dialog and see if it works.

Comment: @cafebabe1991  I'm very green to Android dev, so while your explanation is good, it all sounds Greek to me. A little example will help. Pls.

Comment: My bad :-). Ill try to explain, first you have to create a dialog box , and then we decorate this dialog just like the one shown above. To do that we create our own layout (since by default, android will decorate it in its own way, which you dont want) in which we place things like a zoom controller etc. And now when we show the dialog box it appears like the one we see above

Comment: @cafebabe1991, can you show me an example in code?